# Making jquery ajax post request when post body content is JSON but response is HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making below jquery ajax post request:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/foo',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: JSON.stringify(barsJSON),
                success: function (responseHTML) {
                    $('#content').html(responseHTML);
                }

                });
```

The server expect post body content to be of type JSON but the response the server sends is HTML. Is above correct?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Dzhambazov `type` is an alias for `method`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the contentType

example contentType : 'application/json'

Answer (score 3):

content Type is missing
add `contentType : 'application/json'`

Answer (score 1):

You should mention the content type in ajax call 
Eg: contentType:"application/json"